# Add random noise in each value of CSV rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, csv, data-preprocessing

I am trying to add some random noise to my csv columns except last column.

This is my csv file:

```
z-1            z-2          z-3        z-4         z-5        z-6           z-7     class
0.1305512   0.1301835   0.1295706   0.1287125   0.1276091   0.1262605   0.1246666     1
0.151239    0.1508714   0.1502585   0.1494004   0.148297    0.1469484   0.1453545      0
0.1463833   0.1461299   0.1456313   0.1448875   0.1438984   0.1426641   0.1411845     1
0.1422839   0.1419962   0.1414633   0.1406851   0.1396616   0.138393    0.136879       0
0.1452986   0.1450747   0.1446055   0.1438911   0.1429314   0.1417265   0.1402764      1
0.1354216   0.1351467   0.1346265   0.1338611   0.1328504   0.1315945   0.1300933       0
0.1458855   0.1456223   0.1451139   0.1443602   0.1433613   0.1421172   0.1406278      1
0.149526    0.1492658   0.1487604   0.1480096   0.1470137   0.1457725   0.144286       0
0.1452744   0.1450098   0.1444999   0.1437448   0.1427444   0.1414988   0.1400079      1
0.146562    0.1462768   0.1457463   0.1449706   0.1439496   0.1426834   0.1411719      0
```

I want to add noise in each value of CSV rows in the range of [0.1, 0.12].

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import random

df = pd.read_csv("./data/raw.csv")

noise = [random.uniform(0.1,0.12) for _ in range(5)] # 5 random floats in the range of 0.1 to 0.12
#print(noise)


for i in noise:
    print(i)
    df1 = df + round((df.iloc[:,:-1] + i),7) # round values after adding noise

df1.to_csv("./data/new.csv", index=False) # make new csv
```

My code generates 5 noises but adds only one noise to every value.

I want to add all generated noise randomly in each rows. I mean 5 noises, randomly add to first row, second row, ....so on. and make new csv.

Is it possible?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to alter each value in your dataframe with a newly generated random noise?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Value shouldn't be alter. It should be in the same position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add random noise to each value individually in the first 5 columns do something like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
for c in df.columns[0:5]:
    df1[c] = df[c] + [random.uniform(0.1,0.12) for _ in range(len(df[c]))]
```

If you want to add random noise to each column individually:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
for c in df.columns[0:5]:
   column_noise = random.uniform(0.1,0.12)
   df1[c] = df[c] + [column_noise for _ in range(len(df[c]))]
```

Comment: Thanks areobe. Let me try, after that I will get back here.

Comment: Hi areobe, This changes my whole csv to one single columns, How do I just save csv without changing its row and column position?

Comment: @Codeholic what do you mean? Maybe it is because you tried to open it with excel. If you want to open it with excel, open excel and select From Text within the Data tab.

Comment: Anyways, I solved my problem, I had to make empty list and append new data to list.  Thanks a lot.